# Fedora 16 fails to boot after Win7 installed a GPT Drive

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, windows, gpt

So, I have Windows 7 and Fedora 16 installed on my old HDD. Everything worked well and fine before I've had my new 3TB drive built in, which I initialized as GPT in Windows. Actually I initialized 1,5TB - the rest remains untouched.

After that Fedora won't boot up anymore. Instead it prompts me to maintenance mode, showing something like:

```
[...]/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sda[number] [...] terminated by signal 15 (Terminated)
```

Whenever I press Ctrl+D it shows one or multiple messages similar to that. Using

```
parted /dev/sdb print
```

shows that the drive as such is recognized as GPT. It also shows up in /etc/fstab. Using older kernels results in the same problem.

What should I do ?

Edit: I initialized the remaining ~1,5TB in Windows - nothing changed.

Comment: Now's a great time to upgrade to Fedora 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try rebuilding the initial ramdisk:

```
/sbin/new-kernel-pkg --package kernel --mkinitrd --dracut --depmod --update `uname -r`
```

Failing that, I'd probably give up and update to F17, which should sort out the problem as well.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I guess it really is a good idea to upgrade now.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall, but reverse the order. Install Win7 first, then Fedora. This method has worked for me. Including Win7 and Win10.
Good Luck!
30years